# Most efficient way of querying secondary index in redis

Tags: c#, lua, redis, stackexchange.redis

What is the most efficient (fastest way) way of querying a secondary index in redis using c#? (Using `StackExchange.Redis`).

The SET `"users:departmentx"` contains keys for 100 000 users or more and the actual user info is stored in a key with the same name as values in the set.

All users are stored like `"user:1"`, `"user:2"` etc.

Executing `"SSCAN" "users" 0 "COUNT" "100"` will return something like:

```
user:1
user:2
user:3
user:4
[...]
```

To get the info I would then call

```
MGET <values from sscan above>
```

Which recieves the right data. But what is the fastest and most efficient way of querying the values for all users, in other words using the output from SSCAN as input to MGET?

Lua-scripting? Pipelining?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're already doing it in the most efficient way available.

The fastest would probably be a Lua script, but doing so will go against the recommendation/requirement for explicitly passing it all touched keys.

Pipelining is always good when possible, but since you're just doing a single `MGET` it will not have an effect.